# If you want to try testing two Android devices(from two manufacturers like Samsung and Pixel) at the same time, would this splitter work?

Tags: android, appium-android, cucumber-java

I am trying to test on two different Android devices as a set first, then Android plus Apple devices set next, while running the test scenario code from my Mac PC with an Appium framework  at the same time. Will this work ? Will this splitter device be useful ?[image: uni USB C to USB Hub 4 Ports, Aluminum USB Type C to USB Adapter with 4 USB 3.0 Ports, Thunderbolt 3 to Multiport USB 3.0 Hub Adapter for MacBook Pro/Air 2020/2019, iPad Pro, Dell, Chromebook and more]

Comment: Pixel is not a manufacturer.

Comment: But yes you can let Android Studio install your app and run it on many devices. There is even an option Select multiple devices. More than four goes easy.

Comment: @blackapps My bad, I know Pixel is the brand of mobile made by Google.
BTW, I am not a mobile app Developer, but a mobile app Tester. Thus the question about testing the same app on multiple devices(manufacturers), and Operating Systems.
Does your answer still holds ?

Comment: If you are a tester then i wonder for what you need a usb splitter. I even wonder for what you need usb to begin with. Are you using Android Studio? And this forum is for programmers.

Comment: @blackapps I am doing mobile app (Flutter based) on different Android devices made by different manufacturers. You know that the GUI element locators differ slightly between manufacturer GUI implementations.
Thus to save time, I can give multiple device details in my testng.xml file and have them connected to the USB hub, to run the same app on multiple devices. I don't know about the possibility, thus I am exploring.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple devices connected, you can go to the devices drop down in Android Studio and, click "Select Multiple Devices...", then select the devices you'd like to run simultaneously. That device, should allow you to have multiple devices connected at once, as any 1-to-many USB splitter would.

(Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 2)

Answer (score 0):

I purchased the device and tried connecting two android devices, which have the application under test already installed, and then when I started the app from with in the IDE while giving both the device configuration given in the testNG.xml file, an error came up saying some session could not be started. I could not figure out what is the real reason.

As I could not run it with two devices, I am believing, it could not be done.
If any one could suggest an answer, it is most welcome